# Getting Response from DSTK (Data Science Toolkit) with Guzzle / Goutte

Tags: php, json, guzzle, goutte

I'm trying to get JSON data back from the Data Science Toolkit, but the response I am getting doesn't have it.  I am trying to pass a string object (json encoded from an array of addresses) to the dstk field, to return a list of coordinates.

Here's the following code snippet:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/']);
$request = $client->post('street2coordinates', ['form_params' => ['body' => json_encode($addresses)] ]);
```

And when I die dump 
   dd($request->getBody()),it just returns the ff object.  or even just $request, I can't pull json data on my search I am expecting Latitude/Longitude coordinates - but I have no idea how/where to get them.

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)[215]
  private 'stream' => resource(8, stream)
  private 'size' => null
  private 'seekable' => boolean true
  private 'readable' => boolean true
  private 'writable' => boolean true
  private 'uri' => string 'php://temp' (length=10)
  private 'customMetadata' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

I have tried using the Goutte client as well, to no avail.  Even trying different methods like ->json() or ->toJson(), no dice.  Help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What happens if in your client you add the option 'debug' => true?  I know that any time I try to access anything from the datasciencetoolkit.org domain I get a connection reset error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to force the body to a string, for example by echo'ing it, or casting it explicitly.

```
echo $response->getBody();
```

Or

```
dd((string)$response->getBody());
```